# Woher kommt der Begriff "Laufhaus"?

Tags: etymology

Mir ist aufgefallen, dass sich Bordelle bei uns (Wien) seit einiger Zeit "Laufhaus" nennen. Vor ein paar Jahren war das noch anders. Woher kommt dieser Begriff?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es handelt sich um eine spezielle Art von Bordell. Bei einem [Laufhaus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laufhaus) haben die Prostituierten ein Zimmer angemietet, die Tür steht offen. Die Kunden laufen von Zimmer zu Zimmer, sprechen mit den Damen und je nachdem ob man sich handelseinig wird, schließen sie die Tür oder gehen weiter.

Comment: Es handelt sich um eine spezielle Art von Hof. Auf einem _Friedhof_ haben die Leichen ein Grab angemietet, der Sarg steht offen. Die Priester laufen von Grab zu Grab, sprechen für die Toten einen Segen, und je nachdem, ob der Verstorbene im Leben redlich war, finden sie dort ihren Frieden.

Answer (score 6):

Einfach mal bei [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laufhaus) nachlesen, da steht zwar nicht viel dazu, aber immerhin, woher der Begriff kommt:

> Die Freier laufen durch die Gänge des Hauses (daher der Name
>   Laufhaus), um unverbindlich mit den anwesenden Damen in ihren Zimmern
>   zu sprechen und danach gegebenenfalls ihre Dienste zu beanspruchen.

Comment: Ich wollte den Begriff vom Arbeits-PC nicht googlen, denn die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass die meisten Treffer NSFW sind, dürfte so bei 100% liegen.

Comment: Hehe, das ist eine plausible Erklärung...

Comment: Seit wann ist die Wikipedia eine vernünftige Quelle für Etymologien?

Answer (score 0):

Erklärend ist vielleicht der Unterschied zu anderen Bordellen zu erwähnen.

Wie man in verschiedenen Filmen/Serien sieht (und ich einmal zufällig erlebt habe) ist es sonst so daß man in ein (Wohnhaus)Haus geht wo es am Eingang eine Lobby o.ä. gibt wo die Damen "vorgestellt"/vorgeführt werden, man sich für eine (oder mehr) entscheidet und dann von dieser mit aufs Zimmer genommen wird (oder per Termin mit "Stammdame").

Laufhäuser sind wohl auch aufgrund der Bauweise eher "neu" bzw. seltener da diese auf mehreren Stockwerken relativ lange Flure mit Einzelzimmern zu beiden Seiten haben die jeweils von einer Dame genutzt werden. Vorher hatte man sowas höchsten als umgebaute Wohnkomplexe, Mietsblöcke, Stundenwohnheime und ähnliches. D.h. diese Häuser sind entweder selten weil Häuser in Wohngebieten je nach Lage nur teilweise geeignet (->Einzelzimmern, Dusche in jedem Zimmer) bzw. umzufunktionieren sind (Lage, Genehmigung für Gewerbe und Umbau) und daher eher extra dafür gebaut worden. Lohnt sich dann auch eher in Groß- bzw. größeren Städten.
Glaube auf der Reeperbahn gab sowas in der Art zuerst.

Answer (score -5):

Der Begriff gewinnt um die Jahrtausendwende an Bekanntheit. Ältere Verwendung schon im 19. Jh. scheint nicht in Bezug zum Prostitutionsgewerbe zu stehen, jedoch im kirchlichen Kontext nichtsdestotrotz mit *Lob, Weihe* und dergleichen vereinbar zu sein. Natürlich ist die Gleichsetzung desselben mit nem Puff nicht anzunehmen.

Die starrsinnig trotz entgegenstehender Gründe auf  literarische Hochsprache geeichte historische Methode führt insoweit zu keinem plausiblen Ergebnis, während die vergleichende Methode mit oberflächlicher Interpretation wenigstens die Möglichkeit weiterer Nachweise nahelegt. So kennt Küpper (Illustriertes Lexikon der deutschen Umgangssprache, Stuttgart: Klett, 1982 - 1984) z.B. auch den *Laufbezirk*, sowie die *Liebesallee*, erklärt diese jedoch nicht zuverlässig.

Ob bspw. Holländischer Einfluss erkennbar wäre, bleibt unterdessen außen vor.

---

Ich hatte vor kurzem ohne weiteres Wissen über jegliche Geschichte des Wortes die steile These aufgestellt, es sei verwandt mit *erlauben*, *Urlaub* und deren Gleichen im Sinne von *Feier*, *Freudenhaus*.

Vgl. auch En. *leap*, Proto-Germanisch **hlaupaną* "to spring, jump", eben daher auch *laufen*;  En. *lop*, PGem **luppijaną* "to jump, dart" (daher vermutlich auch eine Bedeutung *Floh, Spinne*, man denke an den *Flohzirkus*).

Ich verstand den Begriff bisher eher im Zusammenhang mit *Wanderhure*. Ein subtil rauer Ton ist im Milieu nämlich nichts ungewöhnliches. *Laufen* kann an sich *auf den Strich gehen* bedeuten.

Vgl. weiterhin Lat. *lupa* "she-wolf; (slang) prostitute"; eher auch Finnish, Karelian *lupa* "permission, license" ("*From Proto-Germanic *lubą (“praise”), from Proto-Indo-European *lewbʰ- (“to love”)*"); etc. etc.

Wegen der Natur der Sache sei außerdem auf lateinisch *lavan* "waschen" verwiesen, woraus vermutlich *laben* und dem ähnlich "asächs. *laƀon*, nl. *laven*, aengl. *lafian* ‘waschen, baden’" entlehnt sind (DWDS). Siehe dazu heute auch *FKK Clubs*, wo saunieren selbstverständlich ist und doch nur eine Begleiterscheinung; ebenso *Massagesalons* mit sogenanntes Happy-End. Weil *laben* aus *lavan* nur schwerlich zu erklären wäre, ist dies mit Skepsis zu betrachten.

### Aber sicher, ja, rumlaufen kann man in dem Haus, wie in den meisten Häusern des Gastgewerbes.

Dass es sich letzten Endes um einen durch die Architektur geprägten Begriff handelt (s. u. @aderFuXgehtum) ist nicht auszuschließen, aber dass man über das Prostitutionsgewerbe in historischen Quellen tendenziel weniger Material finden würde, falls der Begriff älter ist, sollte klar sein und die Herkunft des Begriff insoweit als **ungesichert** gelten bis zum Beweis des Gegenteils.

PS: Ofensichtlich ist *laf* auch ein Yiddisches Wort, das als Legations-Praefix in vielen Ableitungen "schlecht" bedeutet und wohl über niederdeutsch *lau* (vgl. engl. *lukewarm*) mit *lack* verwechselt worden sein könnte, was ferner mit *Loch* bzw. meinetwegen auch *Luke*, *to look* im Zusammenhang stehen möchte. Das fügt sich zu dem Umstand, dass *Urlaub* eben kein *Abarbeiten* ist. Ferner die *Liebe* oder *lavan*, was oben bereuts angedeitet, auf Negation zu münzen, fällt zwar nicht leicht; mag Zufall sein.

Außerdem führt Kroonen *luppōn, "flea" an und duetet dies als *lupfen*, s.a. *Flohmarkt, Flohzirkus* wie *Jahrmarkt*, *Laufkundschaft*, etc.

PPS: Siehe zudem auch *den Laufpass*. Röhrich (Lexikon der sprichwörtlichen Redensarten) beschreibt dies aus der Soldatensprache als Entlassungspapiere, mit denen der Soldat sich auf der Stellensuch ausweist, und nennt dazu ferner den *Laufzettel*, ohne aber auf die Studenten einzugehen, die sich vor der Vorlesungsfreienzeit, will sagen vor dem *Urlaub*, bzw. vor der Abschlussprüfung ihre erbrachte Leistungen und andere Verbindlichkeiten beg-laubigen lassen. Vgl. *Laufbahn* (curriculum), *Lob*, sowie *Passierschein*, *aufpassen* (aufhöhren). Außerdem *verpasst* Röhrich bei *Lack* bspw. die Rotwelsche Tangente. Auf Volkstümelei kann die Antwort nicht beruhen. Weitere Vergleichsmöglichkeiten sind also nicht ausgeschlossen.

Comment: Gibt es Erklärungen zu den vielen Downvotes? Ich finde, die Antwort, sofern mein Laienwissen eine Beurteilung zulässt, erhellt viel Hintergrund und ordnet die akzeptierte Antwort wissenschaftlich(er) ein.

Comment: Haha, direkt drei weitere Downvotes dafür kassiert.

Comment: Weil das ist nicht unsicher, *ich weiß ja wohl was laufen bedeutet, immer ein Schritt nach dem andern und zwar ganz im Gegensatz zu dieser Antwort*. Ja, gut, sei's drum, bisher immer noch net-positive für mich.